# vector collinear condition

Tags: geometry, vectors

In two dimensions, if we have the following vector representantion:

$\vec{PQ}= a \vec{x}+b\vec{y}+c\vec{z}$ and $\vec{QT}= m \vec{x}+n\vec{y}+p\vec{z}$ is it still true that $\vec{PQ}$ and $\vec{QT}$ are collinear iff $\frac{a}{m}=\frac{b}{n}=\frac{c}{p}$.

Comment: If you denote the common ratio as $\lambda$, then the condition becomes $\vec{PQ}=\lambda \vec{QT}$. Hence this common ratio is sufficient for the vectors to be collinear. But it is only necessary so long as $\vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{z}$ are pairwise linearly independent. (If not, it's simple to create counterexamples.)

Comment: @harlem: If you are in two dimensions, why do you have $\vec x$, $\vec y$ and $\vec z$?

Comment: for example if $\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z} $ are the position vectors of the vertices of a triangle.